# Mac OS X hover effect to the icons in web, java, jquery, css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wandering does some one know how to create a MAC OSX hover effect to the icons in web, java, jquery, css???

What do I mean by "Mac OS X effect" ??

as you hovering over with mouse icon zoom in and not only one but icons next to it too.

[example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXBL2BX6Y0I)

Is it possible?

EDIT:

Actually what I want to do is

- some text (color 1)
- some text (color 2)
- some text (color 1)
- some text (color 2)

so the first problem is to set color to every "even" line
second the "mac effect"
and the last one it have to be to draggable (to another div)
 (update color after dragging element out and some how to save it in to cookies for specific user...)
this is the big idea

Answer (score 1):

Here's one in Javascript:

http://safalra.com/web-design/javascript/mac-style-dock/